# How should I handle this review task / answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, review

While reviewing I came across this post: https://superuser.com/a/1359300/926024 and I'm very unsure on what to do about it.

Technically, it *is* an answer to the question, even though it is basically just composed of quotes from other people on another question with a personal story. Overall I think the answer itself is quite bad in quality and should be formatted different, but still, it does answer the question.

The author of this answer got all the quoted information from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/569155/program-doesnt-show-up-in-other-programs-in-open-with-menu) question and I can see a duplicate in those two questions. The exact cases are different, but still very similar and the same answer applies.

What's the course of action one should take with this answer? Edit it to strip it down to its technical aspects? Flag it for deletion and mark the question as a duplicate or leave a comment to hint to the other question? Leave it as it is?

For now I've clicked the "No action needed" button but the wording and the personal anecdotes just don't feel perfect in an answer to me, even though the technical bits are good advise.

Edit: [Screenshot of the by-now deleted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuEHD.png)

Comment: Answer deleted. The OP should have flagged to close as a dupe of the other  question and his answer is really a "thanks' for the referenced answer which is not allowed.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's what I was worried about, but since the questions are both years old and haven't been flagged as duplicates I was unsure on if not the answer itself - obviously without all the personal anecdotes - might've been appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes 100% sense to delete.  There have been many useful answers that are in the form of "Here is what will help you _____".  To have this be more flowery with "Here is my story, man it was tough.  This link was so awesome and saved me _____."  doesn't seem like that far afield of the same usefulness.